# Загрузка формы в зависимости от выбранного чекбокса

Tags: javascript, html

подскажите в какую сторону нужно "копать" для реализации такого вида структуры:

> Страница на ней расположены два чекбокса и кнопка  Чек1 - Чек2 - Далее

Интересует как сделать загрузку формы в зависимости от выбранного чекбокса, то есть если выбран Чек1 и нажата кнопка Далее загружается Форма1, если выбран Чек2 загружается форма 2

Comment: а что уже сделано? что именно не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    function check() {
      let chk = document.querySelectorAll('.chk')
      chk.forEach(function(el) {
      if (el.checked)
        console.log(el);
      })  
    }
```

```html
    <input class='chk' type="checkbox">
    <input class='chk' type="checkbox">
    <button onclick='check()'>далее</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pvfo49sr/1/

ИЛИ

```js
    function check() {
      let chk = document.querySelectorAll('.chk')
      chk.forEach(function(el) {
      if (el.checked)
        console.log(el);
      })  
    }
    
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
    btn.addEventListener('click',() => check() )
```

```html
 <input class='chk' type="checkbox">
     <input class='chk' type="checkbox">
     <button class='btn'>далее</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pvfo49sr/